# Mobile Chrome disable long tap popup

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, contextmenu

We have an application with a custom context menu. Whenever a user selects a specific part of the text this custom context menu will popup and allow users to interact with their selection.

In desktop browsers we can add an event listener for the contextmenu to prevent it(prevent default behavior). However this doesn't work on the mobile version of Chrome(Android).

Whenever we select something on mobile Chrome (hold tap) a context menu saying: COPY SHARE SELECT ALL will appear on top of our custom context menu.

How do we disable the default mobile Chrome context menu so our own context menu will show? Text should remain selectable.

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome 59 on Android 6.0.1:

I have had the same problem in the following context:

- My page has an option to put a lot of little divs in front of my main document as labels/annotation.  I use "position: absolute" and z-index to do this.

  - When I do that and and try to raise my context menu, I get the "Copy Share Select All" menu.
  - If I am careful to get all the little div's out of the way  on touchstart, then my context menu will come up on long touch.
  - I am getting them "out of the way" by setting their innerHTML to null.  I don't have style.width or style.height set for the divs.  Simply setting their (style.left, style.top) to (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) does not seem to work.

Hope this helps.